# How do I add child object to parent object in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, model-view-controller

I'm pretty new to rails so this seems like a pretty easy thing to do. I created a *workout* resource by the using the rails command  generate `scaffold workout name`. Then I created a rails model with `rails g model workout_id`. After that, I added `has_many` to *workout* and `belongs_to` to *weeks*.

```
class Workout < ApplicationRecord
has_many :week
end

class Week < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :workout
end
```

All I want to be able to do is click a *button/link* on the `workout/show` page to add a *week* to that particular *workout*. 
Is the best way to do this to add an addPages action to *workouts* or a create action on the *weeks* class? I want the show page to reload itself updated with the proper amount of weeks. I've tried something like

```
def addWeek
@week = Week.create()
@workout.week << @week
end
```

but I'm getting some errors.

Comment: You can simply do `@workout.weeks.create(attr1: value1, attr2: value2)` or the other way (a bit messier) : `Week.create(attr1: value1, attr2: value2, workout: @workout)`

Comment: This is correct, so how would I route this action?
using a put ?

Comment: The mapping between the action purpose and the HTTP verb is the following : Creation => POST, Update => PUT (or PATCH), destruction => DELETE, retrieve (read) => GET (http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html)

Comment: I've routed the action with a put , and then linked the button with addWeek_workout_path, but I'm getting No route matches [GET] "/workouts/1/addWeek", any suggestions?

Comment: the request is sent as a GET, use `method: :post` as an argument to your `link_to` / `button_to` (see the doc's example with Destroy action : https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to)

Comment: Thanks for the help mryoshi

Answer (score 0):

**Route**

```
resources :workouts do
  post :addWeek, on: :member
end
```

**View**

```
= link_to "Add", add_week_workout_path(@workout), method: :post
```

**Controller**

```
def add_week
  @workout.weeks << Week.create
end
```

**Model**

```
class Workout < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :weeks
end

class Week < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :workout
end
```